# Search for double quotes with InStr

Tags: excel, vba

I want to look into a string and check if it contains `"`.

I tried `If InStr(myString, """) > 0 Then` but VBA reads it as a missing `"` somewhere and returns me a

> Compile error. Expected list separator

How should I search for that character?

Comment: You can use Chr(34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Chr(34)`

```
If InStr(myString, Chr(34)) > 0 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

MS Office has up 4 different kinds of double quotes, including simple text quotes and fancy "smart" quotes, so if you want your VBA code to work consistently you will likely need to check for all of these possible characters that can represent double quotes:

```
If InStr(inputText, Chr(34)) > 0 Or InStr(inputText, Chr(147)) > 0 Or InStr(inputText, Chr(148)) > 0 Or InStr(inputText, Chr(132)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Found double quotes"
Else
    MsgBox "Did NOT find any double quotes."
End If
```

Here is an example with a function I used to replace any special/fancy quotes with regular plain text quotes:

```
Dim d1 As String
Dim d2 As String
Dim d3 As String
Dim d4 As String

Sub FixFormatting()
    Dim inputText As String
    Dim outputText As String
    
    inputText = Range("A2").Text
    d1 = Chr(34)
    d2 = Chr(147)
    d3 = Chr(148)
    d4 = Chr(132)
    
    If InStr(inputText, d2) > 0 Or InStr(inputText, d3) > 0 Or InStr(inputText, d4) > 0 Then
        inputText = ReplaceFancyQuotes(inputText)
    End If
    outputText = inputText
    
    Range("C2").Value = outputText
End Sub

Function ReplaceFancyQuotes(s As String) As String
    s = Replace(s, d2, d1)
    s = Replace(s, d3, d1)
    s = Replace(s, d4, d1)
    ReplaceFancyQuotes = s
End Function
```

Comment: Side note: Why `While` .. `Wend`? A simple replace suffices (could be done in a loop through `Chr` values assigned to an array as well).